# How to install .NET Compiler platform SDK (Roslyn APIs) in Visual Studio for Mac?

Tags: roslyn, visual-studio-mac

Is it possible to get .NET Compiler platform SDK in Mac OSx? I need to utilize it's APIs.

VS for Mac installer does not support to add the SDK as it does in windows VS installer. Also, the .NET Compiler platform SDK extension comes as .vsix file which is not supported in VS for Mac.

Comment: Have you looked for the libraries in NuGet.org?

Comment: Thank you Paulo.I found this, Microsoft.Net.Compilers.netcore 1.3.2. Let me see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project -> Add NuGet packages... search "roslyn". I worked fine with me